# Releasing CAPS LOCK with the SHIFT key

Tags: keyboard, lightdm, capslock

I want my Shift key to do caps and special characters without being affected by Caps Lock.
I want to release Caps Lock with Shift.
I don't want Shift to toggle.

How can I do this?

Comment: What you want is not how it works.

Comment: I'd write a program that'll use sth like Xdo. Won't work with wayland though. Standard keyboard drivers are not capable of doing this